# Restrict the user to login to an URL from mobile

Tags: gui-design, mobile

I am currently working as a product owner for a web based application. We have a requirement to restrict the mobile uses to access our URL from the mobile. I would like to know the standard UI pattern followed to show that message and UI experience.
Can someone suggest a standard message shown to the mobile users saying that the user cannot access this URL from mobile.

Comment: Can you provide some more context around the type of web application it is and the type of users that you have? It will help to elicit more specific and context-related details in the answers provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the users the reason why they can't access the site from their mobile device and nicely ask them to open it from a different device.

> Because of security reasons 'name of product/website' can't be accessed from mobile devices. Please use your computer to open 'product/website'.

Comment: Can you please provide more explanation to show why this is a good option, preferably with some references as well?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that it's not the user fault. Ask nice and be delightful like Pectoralis Major mentioned.

Try to explain the reason according to your user's mental model and not like machine or security lingo.

Comment: Can you please provide more explanation to show why this is a good option, preferably with some references as well?

Answer (score 0):

"{{application name}} is not available for mobile devices. Send us an [Email](https://google.com) and tell us why a mobile experience is important to you".

Comment: Can you please provide more explanation to show why this is a good option, preferably with some references as well?

Answer (score 0):

The standard UI pattern for communicating that a URL cannot be accessed from a mobile device is to display a modal or pop-up message that is prominently displayed on the screen. The message should clearly indicate that the URL cannot be accessed from a mobile device and provide a reason or explanation for the restriction, if necessary.

As for the message, here is a suggestion:

1. "This URL is not available on mobile devices. Please switch to a desktop computer to access this content."
2. "Mobile access to this URL is restricted. Please use a desktop computer for the best experience."
3. "This content is only available on desktop computers. We apologize for the inconvenience."
4. "To access this URL, please use a desktop computer or switch to a larger screen."
5. "This URL is optimized for desktop viewing. Please visit us on a desktop computer for the full experience."

It is also important to provide alternative solutions or suggestions for accessing the content if possible, such as redirecting the user to a mobile-friendly version of the site or providing a link to download the desktop application. **The goal is to provide a clear and concise message while also being helpful and user-friendly.**

Comment: As a user, I wouldn't like any of those messages. None of them explain *why* your application has gone out of its way to prevent me from doing something that seems natural. It should at least warn me what to expect when I bypass the mobile test.

Comment: @RayButterworth I mean, it's a terrible UX requirement in the first place, so it's probably hard not to make it unpleasant to encounter! However, it's surprising that multiple answerers here understood OP's question in reverse...

Answer (score 0):

The elephant in the room here is what happens if someone *does* use the application on a mobile phone?

I for one would certainly try it to see what happens, using a browser extension that breaks the test your application uses.
Will there be a major security problem, will the display be ugly, do you simply not want to worry about supporting mobile devices, etc.?

Would casting the mobile screen to a large monitor somehow be different from using a desktop directly attached to that same monitor?

Whatever the answers are, the message presented to the user should be truthful and non-evasive.

Never tell me *I can't* do something; tell me *why you* don't want me to do it.
(Even if the message is "*Sorry, it doesn't make sense to us either, but our company administration has ruled that we should try to prevent this product's use on mobile devices.*", it would be a lot less frustrating for me as a user.)